# Where does this call go?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, x86, elf

Maybe this is too simple for cpp developers bui I can not figure out..

How does addressing work in this simple object file on lines "3f" and "2d"?
Where does 14 and 0 indexes come from?

```
2d:   e8 e2 ff ff ff          callq  14 <_ZL9privatef2v>
3f:   e8 bc ff ff ff          callq  0 <_ZL8privatefii>
```

**Full disassembly:**

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_ZL8privatefii>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   7:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
   a:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
   d:   8b 55 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
  10:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
  12:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  13:   c3                      retq

0000000000000014 <_ZL9privatef2v>:
  14:   55                      push   %rbp
  15:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  18:   b8 86 00 00 00          mov    $0x86,%eax
  1d:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  1e:   c3                      retq

000000000000001f <_Z3fooii>:
  1f:   55                      push   %rbp
  20:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  23:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  27:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  2a:   89 75 e8                mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)
  2d:   e8 e2 ff ff ff          callq  14 <_ZL9privatef2v>
  32:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  35:   8b 55 e8                mov    -0x18(%rbp),%edx
  38:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  3b:   89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
  3d:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
  3f:   e8 bc ff ff ff          callq  0 <_ZL8privatefii>
  44:   c9                      leaveq
  45:   c3                      retq

0000000000000046 <main>:
  46:   55                      push   %rbp
  47:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4a:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  4e:   be 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%esi
  53:   bf 0a 00 00 00          mov    $0xa,%edi
  58:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  5d <main+0x17>
  5d:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
  60:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  65:   c9                      leaveq
  66:   c3                      retq
```

**Relocation table:**

```
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE
0000000000000059 R_X86_64_PC32     _Z3fooii-0x0000000000000004


RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.eh_frame]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE
0000000000000020 R_X86_64_PC32     .text
0000000000000040 R_X86_64_PC32     .text+0x0000000000000014
0000000000000060 R_X86_64_PC32     .text+0x000000000000001f
0000000000000080 R_X86_64_PC32     .text+0x0000000000000046
```

Comment: I assume you haven't heard of `Intel`, the far superior format?

Comment: No.. Can you give some advice where to read about it?

Comment: is this output form objdump? If so, you can supply it "-M intel". You can read about the difference here: http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm The only objection people have to Intel is that a statement like "MOV EAX, EBX" moving the value of EBX to EAX is "unintuitive", which is bs because that's what "EAX = EBX" does and everyone's fine with that.

Comment: Yes objdump. Here is call with -M intel

 2d:   e8 e2 ff ff ff          call   14 <_ZL9privatef2v>, almost the same. What is 14?? Where does it comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `callq N, text` instructions the N appears to be the address to call, and the text appears to be the label assigned to that address.  So, 0 is the same thing as <_ZL8privatefii> and 14 is the same thing as <_ZL9privatef2v>.

Comment: but it was disassembled from "e8 e2 ff ff ff" where e8 is call instruction regarding to IA-32 instruction set. There is no "14" in raw bytes.

Comment: That's because the operands to call and jump instructions are ***relative offsets***, not absolute addresses.

Comment: e2 ff ff ff is -30 in decimal, which means jump 30 bytes ***back***, starting to count from the address immediately after the current call instruction. That's address 32 in hex -> 50 in decimal, minus 30 gives 20, which in hex is 14.